# How to customize a NSSlider

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsslider

I'm trying to implement a custom slider in Cocoa with 5 values. See my demo project, which can be downloaded here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07311576247413689572.

[image: Custom Slider]

I've subclassed the *NSSliderCell* and implemented methods like `drawKnob:(NSRect)knobRect` and `drawBarInside:(NSRect)cellFrame flipped:(BOOL)flipped` etc.

I'm facing some issues:

1. I'm not able to position the knob correctly regarding to the background image. I know that I'm able to change the knob's frame, and I've tried doing some calculation to position the knob correctly, but I'm not able to make it work for my custom slider. Could someone please help me with this?
2. The height of my custom slider background is 41px. In the `drawBarInside:(NSRect)cellFrame flipped:(BOOL)flipped` I change the height of the frame to 41px as well, but the entire background is not visible. Why?
3. I've noticed that the included images (the background and knob) are flipped vertically. Why? Note that the border top is darker in the background compared to the bottom, but this is reversed when I draw the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I found a mistake in your calculation of the x position of the knob rectangle:  You used the height of the image where you should have used the width.
2. The cell drawing is being clipped to the frame of the control.  Maybe you could expand the control frame when your cell awakes.
3. You need to use the NSImage method `drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:`, and pass YES for the `respectFlipped:` parameter.  Apple's controls generally do use flipped coordinates.

Added: Expanding the frame in `awakeFromNib` doesn't seem to work, the frame gets set back.  Here's something that does work.  Instead of overriding `drawBarInside:flipped:`, add this override:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSRect controlFrame = [controlView frame];
    float bgHeight = self.backgroundImage.size.height;
    if (controlFrame.size.height < bgHeight)
    {
        controlFrame.size.height = bgHeight;
        [controlView setFrame: controlFrame];
    }

    [self.backgroundImage
        drawInRect: [controlView bounds]
        fromRect: NSZeroRect
        operation: NSCompositeSourceOver
        fraction: 1.0
        respectFlipped: YES
        hints: NULL];
    [self drawKnob];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 1+3 solved my issues. I'm still having some troubles trying to change the height. Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: If I use AutoLayout and add a height constraint to my NSSlider in my *nib* to exactly 66, it seems that I'm able so see the entire cell. Why this value?

Comment: No idea why that autolayout setting would work.  An example is added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer. I'll reward you a small bounty, but you'll have to wait 24 hours.